# In debug mode all program run well, but in Release mode I have error in cudaMalloc operation

Tags: c++, c

In debug mode program run well, but in Release mode have error memcpy operation

```
 CellBot *hCellList;
        CellBot *dCellList;
        size_t CellSize = WorldConst.numberOfCells * sizeof(CellBot);
        assert(!((hCellList = (CellBot *)malloc(CellSize)) == NULL));
        gpuAssert(cudaMalloc((void**)&dCellList, CellSize));


        ::memcpy(hCellList, CellList.data(), CellSize);
        gpuAssert(cudaMemcpy(dCellList, hCellList, CellSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Don't have any ideas about that. I always work in debug mode and when decide to make Release have such error.
Program stop on this line of code:

::memcpy(hCellList, CellList.data(), CellSize);

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB9820C447 (vcruntime140.dll) in OgreCu_0.01.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.

Visual studio show error in memcpy.asm
line mark **

```
 CopyUp:
        cmp     r8, 128
        jbe     XmmCopySmall

        bt      __favor, __FAVOR_ENFSTRG ; check for ENFSTRG (enhanced fast strings)
        jnc     XmmCopyUp               ; If Enhanced Fast String not available, use XMM

        ; use Enhanced Fast Strings
        ; but first align the destination dst to 16 byte alignment
        mov     rax, r11                ; return original destination pointer
        mov     r11, rdi                ; save rdi in r11
        mov     rdi, rcx                ; move destination pointer to rdi
        mov     rcx, r8                 ; move length to rcx
        mov     r8, rsi                 ; save rsi in r8
        mov     rsi, r10                ; move source pointer to rsi
        **rep     movsb                   ; copy source to destination buffer**
        mov     rsi, r8                 ; restore rsi
        mov     rdi, r11                ; restore rdi
        ret
```

I change  `::memcpy(hCellList, CellList.data(), CellSize);` to

```
for (int e = 0; e < WorldConst.numberOfCells; e++)
    {
        hCellList[e] = CellList[e];
    }
```

And the **same error** in `hCellList[e] = CellList[e];`

structure of CellBot

```
struct CellBot
{
    int mainId;
    int subId;

    Vec3 coord;
    Vec3 speed;
    Vec3 nspeed;
    Vec3 velocity;
    Vec3 nvelocity;

    float radiusView;
    float radiusAttraction;
    float radiusRepulsion;

    float forceAttraction;
    float forceRepulsion;

    float radius;
    float mass;
    float frictionBounce;

    int colorId;
    int groupId;

};
```

Vec3:

```
template <typename T=float>
class XVector3
{
public:

    typedef T value_type;

    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f), z(0.0f) {}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3(T a) : x(a), y(a), z(a) {}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3(const T* p) : x(p[0]), y(p[1]), z(p[2]) {}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3(T x_, T y_, T z_) : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_)
    {
        VEC3_VALIDATE();
    }

    __host__ __device__ inline operator T* () { return &x; }
    __host__ __device__ inline operator const T* () const { return &x; };

    __host__ __device__ inline void Set(T x_, T y_, T z_) { VEC3_VALIDATE(); x = x_; y = y_; z = z_;}

    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator * (T scale) const { XVector3<T> r(*this); r *= scale; return r; VEC3_VALIDATE();}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator / (T scale) const { XVector3<T> r(*this); r /= scale; return r; VEC3_VALIDATE();}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator + (const XVector3<T>& v) const { XVector3<T> r(*this); r += v; return r; VEC3_VALIDATE();}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator - (const XVector3<T>& v) const { XVector3<T> r(*this); r -= v; return r; VEC3_VALIDATE();}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator /(const XVector3<T>& v) const { XVector3<T> r(*this); r /= v; return r; VEC3_VALIDATE();}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator *(const XVector3<T>& v) const { XVector3<T> r(*this); r *= v; return r; VEC3_VALIDATE();}

    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T>& operator *=(T scale) {x *= scale; y *= scale; z*= scale; VEC3_VALIDATE(); return *this;}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T>& operator /=(T scale) {T s(1.0f/scale); x *= s; y *= s; z *= s; VEC3_VALIDATE(); return *this;}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T>& operator +=(const XVector3<T>& v) {x += v.x; y += v.y; z += v.z; VEC3_VALIDATE(); return *this;}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T>& operator -=(const XVector3<T>& v) {x -= v.x; y -= v.y; z -= v.z; VEC3_VALIDATE(); return *this;}
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T>& operator /=(const XVector3<T>& v) {x /= v.x; y /= v.y; z /= v.z; VEC3_VALIDATE(); return *this; }
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T>& operator *=(const XVector3<T>& v) {x *= v.x; y *= v.y; z *= v.z; VEC3_VALIDATE(); return *this; }

    __host__ __device__ inline bool operator != (const XVector3<T>& v) const { return (x != v.x || y != v.y || z != v.z); }

    // negate
    __host__ __device__ inline XVector3<T> operator -() const { VEC3_VALIDATE(); return XVector3<T>(-x, -y, -z); }

    __host__ __device__ void Validate()
    {
        VEC3_VALIDATE();
    }

    T x,y,z;
};

typedef XVector3<float> Vec3;
typedef XVector3<float> Vector3;

// lhs scalar scale
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ XVector3<T> operator *(T lhs, const XVector3<T>& rhs)
{
    XVector3<T> r(rhs);
    r *= lhs;
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ bool operator==(const XVector3<T>& lhs, const XVector3<T>& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z == rhs.z);
}
```

Comment: What error? Do we have to guess?

Comment: you are supposed to provide a [mcve]  see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @talonmies  try to show all information

Comment: this is a problem in your host code, not in CUDA.  I believe a complete [mcve] is needed to make further progress

Comment: @Robert Crovella What to show more? code, error, line of error, the main idea that it work in debug mode and don't work in release

Comment: A complete code is something that someone else could copy, paste, compile, and run, without having to add anything or change anything, and see the issue.  It is not asking for *your whole code*.  It is asking for a small example code that is like your code, but demonstrates the issue.  It needs to be somethign that someone else can compile and run, without having to build a complete code around it.  Yes, it generally requires effort on your part.  If it's still unclear, please re-read the [mcve] (<-click here and read) writeup.

Comment: In all likelihood the problem is occurring in code you haven't shown. I would guess something has hosed the stack well before anything you have shown here. It would be 99% certain that this has nothing to do with CUDA at all

Comment: @talonmies You are right, I change ::memcpy(hCellList, CellList.data(), CellSize); to

for (int e = 0; e < WorldConst.numberOfCells; e++)
    {
        hCellList[e] = CellList[e];
    }

And the same error in hCellList[e] = CellList[e]; but I dont understand where problem of it

Comment: @talonmies I delete assert(! from program at all. And program go forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very hard to understand your question. Please write a more complete error message and explanation of what you are doing next time!

My guess however is, that you run into the following problem: `assert` statements are slow and therefore usually only compiled into your code in debug mode. In the release mode they are usually simply ignored.

In your code however, you are using a `malloc` inside an `assert`. Therefore in the debug version you get the memory you want, and in the release version you get nothing and the program crashes. The line is:

```
assert(!((hCellList = (CellBot *)malloc(CellSize)) == NULL));
```

What you should do instead is:

```
hCellList = (CellBot *)malloc(CellSize);
assert(!(hCellList == NULL));
```

Comment: I delete assert(! from program at all. And program go forward but show next error with Ogre engine. Thanks!